# How to read and insert bytea columns using psycopg2?

Tags: python-3.x, psycopg2, postgresql-9.3

I am working on a `Python` script to replicate some `Postgresql` tables from one environment to another (which does a little more than `pg_dump`). It works except when I am copying a table that has `bytea` data type.

I read the source table data in memory, then I dump the memory in the target database with concatenated inserts.

Here is my method that produces an insert statement:

```
def generateInsert(self, argCachedRow):

    colOrd = 0;

    valClauseList = []

    hasBinary = False

    for colData in argCachedRow:
        colOrd += 1
        colName = self.colOrdLookup.get(colOrd)
        col = self.colLookup.get(colName)
        dataType = col.dataType

        insVal = None

        if colData is not None:

            strVal = str(colData)
            if dataType.useQuote:

                if "'" in strVal:
                    strVal = strVal.replace("'", "''")
                insVal = "'%s'" % strVal
            else:
                if dataType.binary:
                    hasBinary = True
                    #insVal = psycopg2.Binary(colData)
                #else:

                insVal = strVal
        else:
            insVal = "NULL"

        valClauseList.append(insVal)

    valClause = ", ".join(valClauseList)

    if hasBinary:
        valClause = psycopg2.Binary(valClause)

    result = "INSERT INTO %s VALUES (%s)" % (self.name, valClause)

    return result
```

which works with every table that doesn't have binary data.

I also tried (intuitively) to wrap just the binary column data in `psycopg2.Binary`, which is the commented out line and then not do it to the whole row value list but that didn't work either.

Here is my simple DataType wrapper, which is loaded by reading Postgres' information_schema tables:

```
class DataType(object):
    def __init__(self, argDispName, argSqlName, argUseQuote, argBin):
        self.dispName = argDispName
        self.sqlName = argSqlName
        self.useQuote = argUseQuote
        self.binary = argBin
```

How do I read and insert bytea columns using `psycopg2`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you have this database structure:

```
CREATE TABLE test (a bytea,
                   b int,
                   c text)
```

then inserting binary data into the request can be done like so, without any wrappers:

```
bin_data = b'bytes object'
db = psycopg2.connect(*args)  # DB-API 2.0
c = db.cursor()
c.execute('''INSERT INTO test VALUES (%s, %s, %s)''', (bin_data, 1337, 'foo'))
c.execute('''UPDATE test SET a = %s''', (bin_data + b'1',))
```

Then, when you query it:

```
c.execute('''SELECT a FROM test''')
```

You'll receive a [`memoryview`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview), which is easily converted back to `bytes`:

```
mview = c.fetchone()
new_bin_data = bytes(mview)
print(new_bin_data)
```

Output: `b'bytes object1'`

Also, I'd suggest you not to assemble queries by string formatting. `psycopg2`'s built-in parameter substitution is much more convenient and you don't have to worry about validating data to protect from SQL injections.

Comment: how about when there are other, non-binary columns in the table

Comment: I am still struggling with concatenating the binary into my insert string

Comment: the problem is that my list of columns is dynamic (because i use the same function for every table, each of which has its own set of columns) and here is where it's breaking: `valClause = ", ".join(valClauseList)` when one of the items in the `valClauseList` is binary

Comment: @amphibient as I mentioned, you should use `psycopg2`'s parameter substitution. How are you executing your query? If you have a variable amount of columns, you can simply format the query string like that: `'... VALUES ({})'.format(', '.join(['%s'] * len(valClauseList)), valClauseList)`

Comment: i concatenate the final insert string as though i was to run it in a plain SQL client. then I do `cursor.execute(insSql);`

Comment: @amphibient is it a neccesity in your app to have an assembled string? Because there's a lot of issues that could arise from such actions (SQL injections, for example)

Comment: it is a freestanding script, there is no SQL injection hazard

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125741/discussion-between-leva7-and-amphibient).

Comment: i don't know how to answer your question ("is it necessary") because i am using the same API to read and insert every table in the DB. some have 2 and some have 102 columns...

Comment: i also want to say thanks for bringing this passing a list of values to `cursor.execute()` as a parameter and not as a pre-concatenated insert string -- it is MUCH faster

Comment: @amphibient Even if you aren't worried about security, you don't want to shoot yourself in the foot later when you try to insert a string containing a single quote or something.

Comment: Thanks for this line "new_bin_data = bytes(mview)" :) I was tryed showing photo in http request

Comment: "You'll recieve a memoryview, which is easily converted back to bytes:"    It answers:TypeError: 'memoryview' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: I am also getting TypeError: 'memoryview' object cannot be interpreted as an integer. The problem is `c.fetchone()` returns a tuple, so you have to change the code like this:   `mview = c.fetchone()[0]`