# Deserialize postgres bytea in Python

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql

I'm trying to read a column in a postgres table that is stored as a bytea.

Following the methods outlined here ([How to read and insert bytea columns using psycopg2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40049046/how-to-read-and-insert-bytea-columns-using-psycopg2))

I'm trying to convert a memoryview into the 'real' value. However this returns the following error message:

```
c = db.cursor()
c.execute("""select bytea_column from table
where bytearray_id_ = 'abc123';""")
mview = c.fetchone()

TypeError: 'memoryview' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I've also tried reading the value into a pandas dataframe, and then trying to deserialize the value received there. However this just returns a series and it doesn't seem like much can be done with it.

```
dataframe = pd.read_sql_query(bytea_query, db_string)

dataframe["bytea"]
0    [b'\xac', b'\xed', b'\x00', b'\x05', b's', b'r...
```

Is there an alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ended up being relatively straightforward:

```
data = dataframe["bytes_"][0]
bytearray = bytearray(data)
bytearray
```

This returns a bytearray object containing the correct deserialized data from postgres.