# How to convert or cast a bytea to json using python psycopg2 library

Tags: python, psycopg2, postgresql-9.4

A json string is save in column of type bytea in postgres database table. I need to extract the json string using using the psycopg2 library in python. I tried to convert or decode the string in query but I am not able to get extract the json string. The string contains octal sequences and I need to escape them.

Comment: Could you include some example input and expected output (if not obvious)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read and insert bytea columns using psycopg2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40049046/how-to-read-and-insert-bytea-columns-using-psycopg2)

Comment: It did not. I can get/print the byte value but it contains some hex character(eg. \x80\x04\x95V\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\)