# Retrieve a bytea type image and show it in a python dialog

Tags: python, database, postgresql, pyside2

I have a program that uploads images to a postgresql DB. The images are stored as a bytea. Now I want to make the other direction work. I want to get the image and show it in a PySide2 QDialog. The problem is that the displayed image looks like this:

[image: My Dialog]

My code looks like this:

```
logoInfo = dbConn().query.first('''select encode(inhalt::bytea, 'escape')
    from database where bildname = $1 ''', string)
        self.byteObj = bytes(self.logoInfo, 'utf-8')
        self.imgQT = QImage(self.byteObj, 100, 100, QImage.Format_ARGB32)
        self.pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(self.imgQT)
        self.label.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
        self.label.show()
```

I feel like I have encoding / decoding issues. Maybe you know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: [`encode()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-binarystring.html#FUNCTION-ENCODE) will produce a textual representation of your `bytea` so I'm guessing the bytes you're feeding into `self.byteObj` are the bytes of a textual representation of the image, not the actual bytes of the image. Have you tried simply without wrapping `inhalt` in that `encode()`? Can you also show how you're saving/inserting the image before you try to read it this way?

Comment: I convert my file to a base64 string of the image and insert it into the table with decode(value, 'base64'). This definitely works because I can see the image in my preview.

Comment: I tried to do that aswell but the problem is that the DB query is on my server while the rest is on my client. And when I try to execute the SQL query and dont decode beforehand I get the error message: "Result is not JSON-encodeable" when I try to pass the result

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40049312/5298879) you should be able to insert raw bytes and select them raw as well, only needing to cast resulting `memoryview` back to `bytes`, at least in case of `psycopg2`. What db client library do you use?

Comment: Are you completely sure about the size of the image and the format? Try using the bytesPerLine constructor, adding that value after the height (it normally is `bytes_per_pixel * width`).